# Воспроизведение встроенного видео

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

На странице есть два встроенных видео с ютуба, верхнее стоит на автовоспроизведении, нижнее начинает работу, если по нему кликнуть.

Возможно ли реализовать следующий алгоритм - если человек переходит по определенной ссылке и попадает сразу на нижнее видео (будет реализовано с помощью якоря), чтобы верхнее видео не воспроизводилось автоматом, а воспроизводилось наоборот нижнее? и если да, то как это можно реализовать? заранее спасибо

Comment: Вопрос, вероятно, имеет отношение к html и javascript?

Comment: Можно. Проверяйте наличие якоря в ссылке и останавливайте верхнее и включайте нижнее.

Comment: не совсем может правильно меня поняли!если бы я хотел поменять местами воспроизводимое автоматом видео я бы так и сделал-в одном убрал автоплей а в другой добавил!хотим чтобы в зависимости от источника перехода автоматом воспроизводилось либо одно либо другое

Answer (score 0):

Если видео вставлены через iframe, то поможет этот код:

```
// если ссылка вида htp://example.com#video2
if(window.location.hash == '#video2') {
  // удаляем атрибут autoplay у первого видеопроигрывателя #video1
  document.getElementById('#video1').src = document.getElementById('#video1').src.replace(/autoplay=1/g, '');
  // добавляем атрибут autoplay второму видеопроигрывателю #video2
  document.getElementById('#video2').src += '&autoplay=1';
}
```

Comment: Удалить ключ из ссылки и сменить аттрибут из элемента - вещи разные.

Comment: @Aid , конечно, зависит от способа встраивания.

Comment: спасибо за помощь,так не получилось реализовали немного по другому